# Product info with Quotes PDF

Tags: pdf, salesforce-id

Hi i have task to create Quote email and PDF, there are few product info pdf documents, i need to merge the quote line info with existing product info pdf 
document or more than one pdf document. Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Thank you
Jay

Comment: What are you thinking of doing or what have you researched or tried? You could do a VF email template if it's ok to simply make it look nice in the body with no attachments or use some type of code to create an email to send with an attachment. This is a little too open-ended without any attempt on your part.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Thanks for your response, sorry for the late response. This particular question is related to Marketing materials in PDF already exists, based on the product selected by sales person, the list of the PDF files appears and then user choose PDF files to attach, in one of this PDF file i need to insert Quote to the document and send it via email. I found some third party tool which I can use, but i want know is there any way i can do similar task can be done in Apex?

Comment: Are these PDFs already VF pages? That would be doable. If they're just PDFs fromt he outside you've uploaded, then you won't have any easy route to edit them and reconstruct them with a quote in a certain location